# I'm trying to launch my first C++ program in VSC. but it throws an error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"play"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I'm trying to launch this program using VSC Run and Debug, but it throws an error saying `launch: program C:\Users\TechPro424\Desktop\C++\play.exe` does not exist.
From my knowledge, the program should be created by VSC
The program is created when I use the compiler on the command line though.

The files in my `.vscode` folder

c_cpp_properties.json

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:/Users/TechPro424/scoop/apps/gcc/current/bin/gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

launch.json

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "c:/Users/TechPro424/Desktop/C++",
      "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
          "description": "Make output file name same as input file",
          "text": "-o ${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

settings.json

```json
{
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cCompilerPath": "gcc",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppCompilerPath": "g++",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.debuggerPath": "gdb",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cStandard": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppStandard": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.msvcBatchPath": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useMsvc": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.warnings": [
    "-Wall",
    "-Wextra",
    "-Wpedantic",
    "-Wshadow",
    "-Wformat=2",
    "-Wconversion",
    "-Wnull-dereference",
    "-Wsign-conversion"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.enableWarnings": true,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.warningsAsError": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.compilerArgs": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.linkerArgs": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.includePaths": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.includeSearch": [
    "*",
    "**/*"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.excludeSearch": [
    "**/build",
    "**/build/**",
    "**/.*",
    "**/.*/**",
    "**/.vscode",
    "**/.vscode/**"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useAddressSanitizer": false
}
```

Where have I gone wrong here?

Summary:

I tried to run the program using VSC Run and Debug.
I expected the output `play` to appear in the terminal.
What actually happened: I got an error saying `launch: program C:\Users\TechPro424\Desktop\C++\play.exe` does not exist.
The program is created when I use the compiler on the command line though.

Comment: Well does `C:\Users\TechPro424\Desktop\C++\play.exe` exist? If it does not you could have a problem in your code, it could be caused by your antivirus, it could be the wrong filename ...

Comment: `"C:/Users/TechPro424/scoop/apps/gcc/current/bin/gcc.exe"` you have not followed the VSCode MinGW instructions: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: If and when you grow tired of json-files, on Windows you might want to try Visual Studio Community instead. It comes pre-configured and just works right out of the box. It also has a much better source level debugger. Just as an alternative.

Comment: It sounds like you've not configured anything to build your code. This is usually done with tasks.json

Answer (score 0):

First, I had to create a `tasks.json`, as pointed out by Alan Birtles.
I used the one from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw/

Then, I had to set the `preLaunchTask` property in my `launch.json` file to the label of my build task from `tasks.json`